# react native how to enable general gps location for ios

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I saw in the internet that this solution `Linking.openURL("App-Prefs:root");` doesn't support anymore by apple.

I would like to open general location like google maps do in my react native app, when my general location is disabled.

[image]

[image]